# Laravel paginate redirect back, if page does not exist

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, pagination

I have situation.
I have products in wishlist and I have action: "remove" with ajax. 
And I have pagination:

```
$wishlists = Wishlist::with('product')->where('user_id', $profile->id)
             ->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
```

Initially I have 2 pages on pagination. 
When I remove items from wish list, In pagination I have 1 page, but on page I have 2 pages on pagination, because I use ajax. How I can check, if user moved on page, which does not exist on pagination and redirect him on first page pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before query you can check total pages

```
$totalRecords = Wishlist::with('product')->where('user_id', $profile->id)
             ->count();

$totalPage = $totalRecords/10; (where 10 is records per page)
```

> now you check

```
$ajaxpage = 3;
if($totalPage < $ajaxpage){
    $ajaxpage = 1;(get last page)
}
$wishlists = Wishlist::with('product')->where('user_id', $profile->id)
             ->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate($ajaxpage);
```

Comment: No this not working. I want redirect on first page, if page pagination does not exist.

Comment: than do $ajaxpage = 1;

Comment: When I go to "site.com/se?page=3" I get empty result, how I can hidden pagination?